# Regex: If there is a single colon, then add another colon

Tags: java, regex

I was using replaceAll() to change single colons to double colons as a way of "escaping" them. But if someone entered 2 colons or more, then it would not escape the colons.

I tried this `/(:)([^::])/g` as my regex expression. But it removes the charter after the colon e.g:

10:11:12 becomes 10::1::2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for `(?<!:):(?!:)` and replace with `::`

Where `(?<!:)` is a negative lookbehind that assumes there're no colon before a colon and `(?!:)` is a loolahead that assumes there're no colon after the colon.

Documentation on [lookarround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

**Code:**

```
String s = "10:11:12 78:::78";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<!:):(?!:)", "::"));
```

**Output:**

```
10::11::12 78:::78
```

Comment: That is fantastic, regex has never been my strong point. Thanks for sending the article too!